# How to get one stateful session bean using another stateful session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, stateful-session-bean

I want to make one functionality i.e if user changes password from one device, he should get logout from all other devices where he was logged in.

For this I will need to get all other session bean object atleast.
is there any way to get all other objects using some some field in them? Because I can have username common in all bean.

If no is there any other way to implement this functionality

(I am using ejb 3.0 in jboss container)

Comment: You can't, and is not a good solution to your problem! The session must have a dirty check on user entity: if the entity on persistence layer is newer than the session one then logout the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalidate specific jsf bean session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401786/invalidate-specific-jsf-bean-session)