# Invalidate specific jsf bean session

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

How I invalidate a specific bean in a session?

I have this example code.
I test with ExternalContext.invalidateSession(); but it destroy all beans in the session in the application since it destroys the full session.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
class Managed implements Serializable {

       public void invalidate (){
           // lines //
           externalContext.invalidateSession();   
       }

}
```

but, with invalidateSession all beans in the session are destroyed, I want to invalidate only the one specific "Managed" bean, how I do that?

Comment: So you want to invalidate a bean, from within that same bean?

Comment: i only want to invalidate a bean, with externalContext.invalidateSession(); it invalidate all session, but i want to invalidate only a specific session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you're not clear on *how* you want to implement this solution, to start

1. Inject the [`BeanManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) into wherever you plan to execute the logic. It *has* to be a managed component

   ```
   @Inject
   BeanManager beanManager;
   ```

   The bean manager is the component that will grant you access to all the CDI beans (and other stuff) within your context.
2. You then use the `BeanManager` to get a contextual reference to the bean you're interested in

   ```
   Bean<Managed> bean = (Bean<Managed>) beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(Managed.class));
   Managed managedBean= (Managed) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean)

   managedBean = null; //or whatever you want to do with it
   ```

This solution should destroy the active instance of that session bean; if another attempt is made to use that same bean, CDI will most likely create a brand new instance on-demand

Answer (score -1):

While the approach with `BeanManager` is viable, I would suggest slightly different approach.

You should be able to `@Inject HttpSession` into your managed `@SessionScoped` bean and then invoke `invalidate()` on that session.

Something along these lines:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
class Managed implements Serializable {
       @Inject
       HttpSession session;

       public void invalidate (){
           session.invalidate(); //invalidates current session  
       }    
}
```

Yet another way to achieve this is to make use of `FacesContext`. You were on the right track but you need to take one extra step:

```
((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true)).invalidate();
```

Comment: From the original question: _"I test with ExternalContext.invalidateSession(); but it destroy all sessions ins the application."_. With "all sessions" OP means all beans in a session.

Comment: Than you might want to downvote his question instead of my answer maybe? Because if it is like you say, the question itself is pretty inaccurate. Anyway, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No, since from the original comment AND the upvoted and accepted answer, it is clear what the intention was/is. At least for me as well. You effectively have in your answer exactly what the OP is already doing